# How to save a org buffer everytime the todo state changes?

Tags: org-mode, hooks

In both agenda mode or a regular org mode buffer, whenever I change the todo state, I want the buffer to be saved automatically.

Answer (score 3):

**Adding to [`org-trigger-hook`](https://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-trigger-hook) works:**

```
(add-hook 'org-trigger-hook 'save-buffer)
```

Adding to [`org-after-todo-state-change-hook`](https://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-after-todo-state-change-hook) hook **does NOT work**:

I was troubled to see the hook above did not work until I saw the following post on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/orgmode/comments/9sxe3w/save_file_after_toggling_todo_state/

Comment: How did you determine that `org-after-todo-state-change-hook` did not work?

Comment: @NickD simply checked if the file is still marked as modified after state change. i don't think the `save-buffer` is called. i'm not proficient enough to provide more detailed debug info on this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the buffer is saved. There is something happening afterwards that marks the buffer modified again. org-trigger-hook is run at the very end of org-todo so it does  not suffer from this. It would be nice to figure it out and report it as a bug. Thanks for the reply: I just wanted to make sure that my understanding is correct.

Comment: @NickD I can confirm that this still the case as of now.